# Dropping some data while saving dataframe into csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am running redshift query which is having 40 millions of record. But when I am saving into csv file it is showing only 7 thousands of record. Could you please help me how to solve this?

Example:

Code:

```
    conn = gcso_conn1()
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        
        query = "select * from (select a.src_nm Source_System ,b.day_id Date,b.qty Market_Volume,b.cntng_unt Volume_Units,b.sls_in_lcl_crncy Market_Value,b.crncy_cd Value_Currency,a.panel Sales_Channel,a.cmpny Competitor_Name,a.lcl_mnfcr Local_Manufacturer ,a.src_systm_id SKU_PackID_ProductNumber,upper(a.mol_list) Molecule_Name,a.brnd_nm BrandName_Intl,a.lcl_prod_nm BrandName_Local,d.atc3_desc Brand_Indication,a.prsd_strngth_1_nbr Strength,a.prsd_strngth_1_unt Strength_Units,a.pck_desc Pack_Size_Number,a.prod_nm Product_Description,c.iso3_cntry_cd Country_ISO_Code,c.cntry_nm Country_Name from gcso_prd_cpy.dim_prod a join gcso_prd_cpy.fct_sales b on (a.SRC_NM='IMS' and b.SRC_NM='IMS' and a.prod_id = b.prod_id) join gcso_prd_cpy.dim_cntry c on (a.cntry_id = c.cntry_id) left outer join gcso_prd_cpy.dim_thrc_area d on (a.prod_id = d.prod_id) WHERE a.SRC_NM='IMS' and c.iso3_cntry_cd in ('JPN','IND','CAN','USA') and upper(a.mol_list) in ('AMBRISENTAN', 'BERAPROST','BOSENTAN') ORDER BY b.day_id ) a"
        #print(query)
        cur.execute(query)
        result = cur.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        column = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
        sqldf = pd.DataFrame(result, columns= column)
        print(sqldf.count())
        #print(df3)
        
        sqldf.to_csv(Output_Path, index= False, sep= '\001', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything should work correctly. I think the main problem is debugging using [count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html). You expect number of records but docs says:

> Count non-NA cells for each column or row.

Better to use when debugging `DataFrame`:

```
print(len(df))
print(df.shape)
print(df.info())
```

Also you can do it easier using `read_sql`:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


header = True
for chunk in pd.read_sql(
    'your query here - SELECT * FROM... ',
    con=create_engine('creds', echo=True),  # set creds - postgres+psycopg2://user:password@host:5432/db_name
    chunksize=1000,  # read by chunks
):
    file_path = '/tmp/path_to_your.csv'
    chunk.to_csv(
        file_path,
        header=header,
        mode='a',
        index=False,
    )
    header = False
```